# Regex - First Integer in String (skip float)

Tags: ruby, regex

**updated

right now I'm doing

```
a = gets

count = ((a.match(/\d+/)).to_s).to_i.
```

sample input: 2000 of 3.00

actual output: 2000

sample input: 3.00 of 2000

actual output: 3

objective output: 2000 in both cases (skip float)

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The question is still not clear. Can the integer to be extracted be negative or zero? Also, what is to be returned if no integer is present (e.g., nil, :no_integers, zero)? Note that if the integer can be zero you cannot return a zero to indicate that no integer is present.

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
"3.00 of 2000"[/(?<![.\d])\d+(?![.\d])/].to_i    # => 2000
"2000 of 3.00"[/(?<![.\d])\d+(?![.\d])/].to_i    # => 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where you have to know your data. If you know that your input will always have exactly one integer, then the following approach will work:

```
'3.00 of 2000'.split.select { |e| e =~ /^\d+$/ }.last.to_i
#=> 2000

'2000 of 3.00'.split.select { |e| e =~ /^\d+$/ }.last.to_i
#=> 2000
```

The idea is to split each line of input into an array, and then select just the array elements that contain nothing but digits. Finally, the last (and hopefully only) element of the array is converted to an integer.

There are many ways this can blow up or fail to achieve the results you want given arbitrary input. However, it certainly works for the specific corpus you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code:

```
a = gets

a.split(/[\sa-z]+/).select {| v | v !~ /\./ }.last.to_i

# => 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex but...

```
'2000 to 3.00'.split.find { |s| s.to_i.to_s == s }.to_i
 => 2000 
'3.00 to 2000'.split.find { |s| s.to_i.to_s == s }.to_i
 => 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '3 of 20.00, +42,31 of 455, -6 of -23.7 .'
str.scan(/(?<![\.\d])(-?\d+)(?!\d*\.)/).flatten.map(&:to_i)
  => [3, 42, 31, 455, -6]
```

- The capture group `(-?\d+)` consists of one or more digits 0-9, optionally preceded by a minus sign.
- `(?<![\.\d])` is a negative lookbehind group, meaning the capture group cannot be preceded by a decimal point or digit.
- `(?!\d*\.)/)` is a negative lookahead group, meaning the capture group cannot be followed by zero or more digits followed by a decimal point.
- `str.scan(/(?<![\.\d])(-?\d+)(?!\d*\.)/) #=> [["3"], ["42"], ["31"], ["455"], ["-6"]]`, which is why `flatten` must be applied before conversion to integers.
- Initially I tried `(?<!\.\d*)` as the negative lookbehind group, but that generated an error.  The reason: negative lookbehinds cannot be variable-length.  I understand the same restriction applies in Perl.

Edit: I somehow overlooked the title of the question. To retrieve just the first integer, either tack `.first` on the end of `str.scan` or replace that statement with:

```
str.match(/(?<![\.\d])(-?\d+)(?!\d*\.)/)[0].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex `[^0-9.]([0-9]+)[^0-9]` will match only numbers adjacent to characters which are not number or dot, and capture the number in the single capture group.

If the numbers can also appear adjacent to beginning or end of string, the fix should be self-evident;

```
(?:^|[^0-9.])([0-9]+)(?:[^0-9.]|$)
```

Comment: The asker did not indicate which characters could precede the integer.  With some interpretation that could be a problem: `'3.0 a20'[/(?:^|[^0-9.])([0-9]+)(?:[^0-9.]|$)/] => "a20"`, `"a20".to_i # => 0`.  Note you can replace `0-9` with `\d`.

Comment: Huh? The capture group still only captures the 20.

Comment: My apologies.  Yes, it captures 20 (e.g. `.match(...)[1]`); I gave the match result.

Answer (score 0):

```
words_containing_non_digits = -> x {x[/\D/]}
p '3.00 of 2000'.split.reject &words_containing_non_digits #=> ["2000"]
```